# Where clause with one to many relation in room database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, rx-java, rx-java2

I have database tables with one to many relationship, now in that i want to fetch only records which contains atleast one matching record in `CClass` table.

Here is my PojoClass where i have defined relation between two

```
public class PojoClass {

    @Embedded
    PClass pClass;

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "cid",
        entityColumn = "cid",
        entity = CClass.class)
    List<CClass> cClassList;

}
```

PClass.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "p_class")
public class PClass {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cid")
    private long cid;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rid")
    private String rid;
}
```

CClass.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "c_class",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = PClass.class,
        parentColumns = "cid",
        childColumns = "cid",
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))
public class CClass {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name="cid")
    @NonNull
    private long cid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "rid")
    private long rid;
}
```

And Dao

```
@Dao
public abstract class ClassDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM PClass")
    public abstract Single<List<PojoClass>> getAll();
}
```

This code works well but i want to ignore the raws for which there is no matching raw in `CClass`. Right now `ClassDao#getAll()` returns empty list for `PojoClass#List<CClass> cClassList` field when there is no data but i want to completely ignore that record from `'ClassDao#getAll()`

Comment: Do you want to get a `PojoClass ` where the `c_id` (a Foreign Key) matches that of a value that you provide?

Comment: No, Right now i am getting expected result with the code. 
but I want  to ignore records where there is no matching records in CClass for corresponding PClass raw.

Comment: I have added more explanation in question, pl read

Comment: Which classes have the *one to many relationship*? And what do you mean *matching records*? I am assuming you want to match by `id`s, hence the Primary Key and Foreign Key?

Comment: Yes, want to match `id`, primary key is `PClass#cid` and foreign key is `CClass#cid` i have properly annotated entity class for relation between those two classes.

So if there is no matching record in CClass for a record from PClass i want to exclude that entire result.

Comment: Did you look at my answer? Lets discuss on the thread there.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your time, but i think i failed to make you understand my problem exactly, i will update this question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you should name your id variables properly. The id variable can be simply **id** where it is the primary key and something other than **id** like **c_id** on the Entity where it is a foreign key.

So edit your `PClass.java` as:

```
@Entity(tableName = "p_class")
public class PClass {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rid")
    private String rid;
}
```

and Since you are telling that you have a one-many relationship from `PClass` to `CClass`, I guess there should be a reference to `PCLass`'s id in the `CClass`. So your `CClass.java` should look like:

```
@Entity(tableName = "c_class",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = PClass.class,
        parentColumns = "id",
        childColumns = "pid",
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))
public class CClass {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name="id")
    @NonNull
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "rid")
    private long rid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "pid")
    private long pid;
}
```

Another thing I do not know what `rid` is.
Now to get resources that represent `CClass` which has the **pid** that you are concerned with:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM c_class WHERE pid = :pId")
    public CClass getCClassForPClass(long pId);
```

Then you will be able to call this DAO function and get the CClass for a PClass id that you are concerned with. Would have been a lot easier if you had the actual model's name instead of this PClass and CClass.

Another thing, IMHO DAO's should be **interfaces** and not **abstract classes**

Comment: Yes i know it should be interface, but i have some code there so abstract class instead of interface and the names were to demonstrate only because original code is much bigger to post here. i will update my question soon.

Comment: I think you could make question better by using some diagram instead :)

Comment: Yes, i was thinking of that, will try my best